# Anyone have a working Jasmine unittest that runs in Resharper 7 EAP?

Tags: unit-testing, resharper, jasmine

I'd really like to be using the R#r test running for my javascript unittests. R#r 7 EAP recognizes the tests but when I launch them the runner shows '... Test wasn't run' for all tests.

I can't find any info on what the R#r test runner expects in terms of configuration/directory structure.

Directory structure and sample test posted [here](http://devnet.jetbrains.net/message/5460039#5460039)

Answer (score 10):

A basic/hardcoded jasmin unit test does work under R#r 7 EAP. This implies that jasmine is *baked in* to R#r i guess. Have an open question regarding same.

```
describe('resharper jasmine testrunner', function () {
    describe('simplest possible test', function () {
        it('should execute', function() {
            expect(true).toBe(true);
        });
    });
});
```

Got a pointer on the [R#r forum](http://devnet.jetbrains.net/message/5460322#5460322) that doc comment references are your 'includes' (or jsTestDriver.conf equiv).

```
/// <reference path="../../libs/testing/jasmine/jasmine.js"/>
/// <reference path="../../libs/crunch/jquery-1.6.2.js"/>
```

Have yet to get my real tests passing though the now run. Investigating fixture paths next.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure how advanced of a solution/structure you're looking for, as I just started looking into this myself, but i have a simple example test "working"*... (using Resharper 7 EAP 7.0.56.103). As far as i know, you can structure your test files anyway/where you want, as long as you include references to all of its dependencies with <reference path="foo/path/file.js" />)

*These pass inside the ReSharper unit tests session window. The browser does not show me any sort of test info but rather a blank screen with some jasmine-related html in the source.

/scripts/cheese.js

```
function Cheese() {
    return {
        isGood: true
    };
}
```

/tests/cheeseTest.js

```
/// <reference path="/scripts/cheese.js"/>
describe('simplest possible test', function() {
    var cheese = null;
    it('cheese is good', function() {
        cheese = new Cheese();
        expect(cheese.isGood).toBe(true);
    });
});
```

Comment: My attempts at using reference path caused tests to fail. Yours is root relative. I'll give that a try and report back. Addtl info in my R#r forum post.  Any chance you are able to debug your javascript under the test runner?

Comment: For me, the debug option in the test runner is disabled.

Comment: True... using other runners you simply set a breakpoint using the browser debugger. The R#r runner is launching a new browser instance per run making this technique invalid.

Comment: This example works for me, but when the test fails (e.g. asserting toBe(false)) the resharper runner is showing me an output of "undefined" "Exception doesn't have a stacktrace".  Do you get a better error?

Comment: @mikebridge I've solved exactly same issue. Fortunately it's already fixed in the Re# 7.1. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11245016/stack-trace-for-jasmine-test-with-the-resharper-7-test-runner

Comment: @zbynour Thanks, I'll try the new version.  This is the bug report: http://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/RSRP-329095